# devise form not saving in ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, devise

i am working in a form where users get invite ..when users click the invite link.it contains hash code stored in invitations table...i have other two regeneration forms too.so i created registrations controller to overide sign up path based user type...

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)

     if resource.planner_type == "planner" 
      '/square/invited_new'

      else
        '/vector/invited_new'

      end
  end

end
```

i added   `devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}`
in  route.rb ..but the vector form is not saving ..it mention invitation_type is not set...in the form i have set the hsacode in session and have checked the hashcode and invitation type of user are same...The vector form is saving once i change to

```
devise_for :users
```

What is happening..please anyone help..i am totally confused..i need both forms to work

Comment: have you tried using path helpers?

Comment: i ahvent used path helpers..how to do it?

Comment: post the result of `rake routes`

Comment: sorry i couldn't fetch the routes..i tried before too..but i used to get error gem file version..but all are set correct..dont what is causing this problem... $ rake routes
←[31mYour Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0←[0m

Comment: You have problem with RVM. please fix it first.

Comment: Install Latest ruby version to work with